# Error 502 Bad Gateway on NGINX + rails + dokku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, nginx, digital-ocean

I am receiving an Error 502 after deploying my Ruby on Rails app to a Dokku droplet on Digital Ocean.  The app builds and deploys to Heroku just fine, as well as locally.

Checking the NGINX logs, I see the following:

```
2014/01/10 01:56:32 [error] 2376#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: <my.ip.add.ress>, server: app.campbellscoop.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:49153/", host: "app.campbellscoop.com"
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: what production web server (webrick/unicorn/thin) are you using? what does that log say?

Comment: NGINX as part of DOKKU.  The log is what was put up top.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem.  Where do you find the nginx logs?

Comment: Can you do 'curl -I http://127.0.0.1:49153/' from the dokku server? Also can you check the logs for the rails app?

Comment: I started getting this out of the blue in previously working dokku images yesterday, set up a fresh new DigitalOcean droplet in hopes to be rid of the issue, but no luck. A fix is yet to present itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the errors by running `dokku logs appname` in the ssh.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and it turned out I didn't use the correct startup command in the Procfile.

Before

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

After

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it's problem in restarting mod_passenger (nginx module for ruby)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue after powering off my Dokku droplet on Digital Ocean.
Easy fix was to ssh into the droplet and run:

```
dokku ps:rebuildall
```

Visit the app in the browser and all was well!