# Nginx errors with Rails+Faye+Puma on Dokku Digital Ocean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, digital-ocean, puma, dokku

Good day!
I want to run websocket app with Faye gem, but the following problem occurs: when I deploy my app on production server, Ngix can't receive faye.js and can't connect to faye server. In Nginx error.log I found next errors:

```
2014/12/24 15:44:39 [error] upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 46.0.121.23, server: example.com, request: "GET /faye HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9292/faye", host: "example.com"

2014/12/24 15:44:39 [error] *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 46.0.121.23, server: example.com, request: "GET /faye HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9292/faye", host: "example.com"
```

I try the [How to start faye server on a rails app deployed using dokku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25135190/how-to-start-faye-server-on-a-rails-app-deployed-using-dokku) and [Error 502 Bad Gateway on NGINX + rails + dokku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21056911/error-502-bad-gateway-on-nginx-rails-dokku) answers, but it's not help for me.

My Procfile is

```
web: bundle exec rails s Puma -p 5000
faye: bundle exec rackup s Puma faye.ru
```

My faye.ru is

```
require 'faye'
require File.expand_path('../config/initializers/faye_token.rb', __FILE__)

class ServerAuth
  def incoming(message, callback)
    if message['channel'] !~ %r{^/meta/}
      if message['ext']['auth_token'] != FAYE_TOKEN
        message['error'] = 'Invalid authentication token.'
      end
    end
    callback.call(message)
  end
end
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 0)
faye_server.add_extension(ServerAuth.new)
run faye_server
```

My nginx.conf is:

```
upstream example.com { server 127.0.0.1:49169; }
server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name example.com;
  location    / {
    proxy_pass  http://example.com;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }
  location /faye {
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_buffering    off;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
    proxy_no_cache     $http_pragma $http_authorization;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9292;
  }
}
```

My app get faye.js next:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "http://example.com/faye.js" %>
```

And connect to faye server

```
$(function() {
    var faye = new Faye.Client('http://example.com/faye');
    faye.subscribe('/comments/new', function (data) {
        eval(data);
    });
});
```

What can I do? In development enviroment all works fine, but in production only errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to config from this gist
https://gist.github.com/Bubelbub/0a942a0d51a3d329897d

In server section:

```
large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;
```

In faye location:

```
 proxy_buffers 8 32k;
 proxy_buffer_size 64k;
```